# Export textboxes, comboboxes data into shared Excel sheet from Windows Forms using C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have below small application and I want to export all data filled by the end-user to be saved into shared excel sheets, which every time new user will fill new data/choose from comboboxes/date picker and click submit it will come continuously in the same sheet without overriding the existing ones.

[image: Windows Form]

Comment: OK that's good. What's your problem? Please, show us your code.

Comment: @H.Pauwelyn still I didn't start with the code, because I don't know from where to start, I retrieved all data in the comboboxes, what's the best solution should I fill the data into datagridview then export it?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, what you want to do is insert some data into an Excel worksheet. For interaction with Excel, Microsoft provides a library called VSTO (Visual Studio Tools for Office).